# Calculating the sum of number difference within a for loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have a dataset which includes some numbers, I want to calculate the sum of the difference in the numbers how do I do this?
For example my dataset looks like this:

Name        Score

Luke        100

Adam        90

James       80

Peter       70

Mike        60

How do I calculate the sum of the difference within a “for loop” in vb.net such that it does something like this below:

(100 - 90) + (90 – 80) + (80 – 70) + (70 – 60) = 40

I tried to do this below, but i am not sure of how to add the difference:

```
Dim i as integer
For i = 0 to ds.tables(0).rows.count
    ds.tables(0).Row(i).Item(1)
    Dim diff = ds.tables(0).Row(i).Item(1) -  ds.tables(0).Row(i+1).Item(1)
    sum = ....
Next
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Joelrobichaud, i have edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Dim totalValue As Integer = 0

    For index = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        totalValue += (CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(index - 1).Item(1)) - CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(index).Item(1)))
    Next
```

You can use totalValue  as your answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to stop the loop before you reach the count, otherwise you will receive an exception.

Second, you need to add a special case for the first item:

```
' The sum of the differences
Dim wSumOfDifferences As Integer
' Start with a non-sensical value for the last value that we processed
Dim wLastValue As Integer = -1

For Each oRow As DataRow in ds.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim wCurrValue As Integer

    ' Get the current value
    wCurrValue = CInt(oRow.Item(1))

    ' If we are not working on the first item, calculate the difference between
    ' the current value and the last value
    If wLastValue <> -1 Then
       wSumOfDifferences += (wLastValue - wCurrValue)
    End If

    ' Record the current value as the last value
    wLastValue = wCurrValue
Next

Console.WriteLine("Sum = " & CStr(wSumOfDifferences))
```